# Remove rows in R data frame based on values in columns not found in a list

Tags: r, radix

I want to remove rows in a data frame based on values in a column that are not found in a list using R base.

I have a data frame simplified looking like the one below:

```
> df
Category.1  Value.1  Category.2 Value.2
         A      0.1           A     0.1 
         A      0.1           A     0.2 
         A      0.1           A     0.3 
         A      0.1           B     0.6 
         A      0.1           B     0.7 
         A      0.1           B     0.8 
         A      0.1           C     0.5
         A      0.1           C     0.8
         A      0.1           C     0.9
         .       .            .      .
         B      0.3           A     0.1 
         B      0.4           A     0.2 
         B      0.5           A     0.3 
         B      0.1           B     0.6 
         B      0.2           B     0.7 
         B      0.3           B     0.8 
         B      0.3           C     0.5
         B      0.8           C     0.8
         B      0.6           C     0.9
         .       .            .      .
         Z      0.1           X     0.1 
         Z      0.1           X     0.3 
         Z      0.1           X     0.4 
         Z      0.1           Y     0.6 
         Z      0.1           Y     0.8 
         Z      0.1           Y     0.4 
         Z      0.1           Z     0.2
         Z      0.1           Z     0.1
         Z      0.1           Z     0.6
```

And I have a list with four values for each category:

```
> List
A      0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4
B      0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6
C      0.5  0.6  0.8  0.9
.       .    .    .    .
Z      0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4
```

I want to filter the data frame for rows that meet certain conditions. More specifically, I want to keep rows which have either the same **Category**, independent of their **Value**, and rows that do not have the same **Category**, but their **Value** is found in the list, respectively.

Simplified: Removing rows, in which

`Category.1` IS NOT EQUAL TO `Category.2`

AND `Value.1` IS NOT IN list matching the name of `Category.1`

OR `Value.2` IS NOT IN list matching the name of `Category.2`

As long as one of the values, either from Category.1 or Category.2 is not found in the list and both Category.1 and Category.2 are different, remove the row.

Now, finding a solution with `dplyr` was quite simple, but I would need a solution in `R base`. Here's the `dplyr` approach that worked:

**dyplr example (working):**

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% 
       filter(ifelse(Category.1 == Category.2, 
                     Category.1 == Category.2, 
                     Value.1 %in% List[[Category.1]] & 
                     Value.2 %in% List[[Category.2]]))
```

I was also able to come up with a solution in `R base` by looping through each row, but it's not the most efficient way, especially with a data frame that has > 10 000 rows, it takes way too long.

**R base example (working, but slow):**

```
df[sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) (df[x,"Category.1"] == df[x,"Category.2"] | 
                                   df[x,"Category.1"] != df[x,"Category.2"] & 
                                   df[x,"Value.1"] %in% List[[match(df[x,"Category.1"],names(List))]] & 
                                   df[x,"Value.2"] %in% List[[match(df[x,"Category.2"], names(List))]])),]
```

Since my main objective here is to subset the data, I have tried using `subset()`, with the following expression:

**subset() approach (not working):**

```
subset(df, Category.1 == Category.2 | 
           Category.1 != Category.2 &
           Value.1 %in% List[match(Category.1, names(List)][[1]] &
           Value.2 %in% List[match(Category.2, names(List)][[1]])
```

This only selects for `Category.1 == Category.2`. Not sure, why it's not working. Anyone with an idea?

Is there a better solution to this?

If it helps, here's the code for a representative data frame and list:

**Example Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(Category.1 = rep(LETTERS, each = 7), Value.1 = rep(seq(0.2, 0.8, 0.1), length(LETTERS)),
                 Category.2 = sample(rep(LETTERS, each = 7)), Value.2 = rep(rev(seq(0.2, 0.8, 0.1)), length(LETTERS)))

List <- setNames(lapply(LETTERS,  function(x) c(0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8)), LETTERS)
```

The values in the list are all the same for simplicity.

Comment: if you give up being stick to base R, I suggest `anti_join`

Comment: The way you print `List` it looks like either a `data.frame` or maybe even a `matrix`, not a `list`. Could you share your data more reproducibly? `dput(head(List))` and `dput(df[1:10, ])` would be copy/pasteable and include all class and structure information - it would make it easier to help you if you include the output from those in the question.

Comment: I have now added a representative data set.

Comment: @GregorThomas I've added both the `df` and the `List`. Sorry for the initial confusion, it was hard to paste a list. To answer your question, the object `List` is indedd of class `list`. `> class(List)
[1] "list"`

Comment: I'm surprised you say the `dplyr` method is working, I get a "recursive indexing" error when I try it on your data.

Comment: @GregorThomas You're right. The `dplyr` example was missing `rowwise()` before the filtering. I have corrected that now in the example above. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much simpler example, where only row 3 should be dropped. With the big example it was too hard to tell what was going on.

```
df <- data.frame(Category.1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), Value.1 = c(.2, .2, .1, .2),
                 Category.2 = c("A", "B", "A", "B"), Value.2 = c(0, .3, .2, .2))

vals = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8)
List <- list(A = vals, B = vals)
```

And here's a working solution. It's a modified version of your working solution, where we bring the `==` out of the `sapply` (it's vectorized), omit the redundant `!=` condition, and use straight name indexing rather than `match`. A `microbenchmark` on the larger data you share makes it look about 2x faster.

```
df[
  df[, "Category.1"] == df[, "Category.2"] | 
  sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) {
  df[x,"Value.1"] %in% List[[df[x,"Category.1"]]] &
    df[x,"Value.2"] %in% List[[df[x,"Category.1"]]]
  }), 
]

#   Category.1 Value.1 Category.2 Value.2
# 1          A     0.2          A     0.0
# 2          A     0.2          B     0.3
# 4          B     0.2          B     0.2
```

Comment: Thanks! That modification did speed things up quite a bit.